# Product attribute creates a duplicate group

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php

From installer I have installed the following attribute but instead of inserting it into a 'inventory' tab it creates another inventory tab. and inserts into new inventory tab.

```
    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'qty_new', array(
        'group'             => 'inventory',
        'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_NUMERIC,
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'New Quantity',
        'input'             => 'text',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => false,
        'comparable'        => false,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'unique'            => false,
        'apply_to'          => '',
        'is_configurable'   => false
    ));
```

Please advise me if you need more information ...

Answer (score 0):

In the backend go to: "catalog" -> "attributes" -> "manage attribute set"
and there select the attribute set that should contain your new attribute, there you can check for the exact name of the group (make sure is the same name), copy the name and put that into your installer script. 
Finally just delete the created attribute and try again.

Comment: i think he wants it in the already exsisting inventory tab

Answer (score 0):

The Inventory tab is not dynamic like other tabs, you can't just add an attribute to this tab.

You can overwrite with it's block: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Inventory.php`

or it's template: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml`